# Filter a property List inside in include

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I need your help

I try to create a linq sentence with .Include but my problem is that i have a property in mi class witch is a list, it is my class specifically:

```
public partial class document
{
    public int       ID     { get; set; }
    public string    Amount { get; set; }
    public List<Log> Log    { get; set; }
}
```

this is the class log

```
public partial class Log
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateLog { get; set; }

    public int? DocumentID{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocumentID")]
    public Document Document{ get; set; }
}
```

my problem is that I don't know how to filter my list record inside the document for include in the class, I need to get the whole document class and filter the log that only shows status = recieved, a document can have many logs

y tried to do that but it didn´t work

```
 var Result = db.document
    .Include(m => m.Log.Where(c => c.Status == Status.Recieved));
```

i recived the next error

> "the include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the select operator for collection navigation properties.\r\nparameter name: path"

I appreciate your help

Comment: This syntax supported only in EF Core 5.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does support some automatic filtering rules to help with concepts like soft-delete (IsActive) and multi-tenancy (ClientId), but not really applicable for scenarios like this where you want to apply a situational filter like "received" documents.

EF entities should be considered as models reflecting the data state. To filter results like that is more of a view model state which you can achieve through projection:

```
var result = db.document.Select(d => new DocumentViewModel
{
    DocumentId = d.DocumentId,
    // .. fill in other required details...
    ReceivedLogs = d.Logs
        .Where(l => l.Status == Status.Received)
        .Select(l => new LogViewModel
        {
             // Fill needed log details...
        }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Otherwise if you are doing something local with the entities and just want the document and the received log entries:

```
var documentDetails = db.document
    .Where(d => d.DocumentId == documentId)
    .Select(d => new 
    {
        Document = d,
        ReceivedLogs = d.Logs
            .Where(l => l.Status == Status.Received)
            .ToList()
    }).Single();
```

`documentDetails.Document.Logs` will not be eager loaded, and would trigger lazy loading if you access it, but the `documentDetails` does contain the relevant Received logs to access. As an anonymous type it's not suitable to being returned, only consumed locally.

Answer (score 1):

`Include` used for include relationships with an entity and fetch related entity properties, check documentation - [Fetching related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/work-with-data-in-asp-net-core-apps#fetching-related-data)
If you select documents without `Include` like this

```
var documents = await db.document.ToListAsync();
```

you get documents data where `Log` will be null.

You need something like that:

```
var result = await db.document
                     .Select(w=> new 
                     {
                         document = w,
                         log = w.Log.Where(c => c.Status == Status.Recieved).ToList()
                     }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thanks for you answer , but i have the next error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean[] ToArray[Boolean](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Boolean])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Include is exactly for fetching related data and NOT for joining. You can remove Include from this query.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You absolutely right about include in query, fixed. Deleted a not entirely correct statement. Thx.